# Select-String, searching for wildcards

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to use PowerShell to find hits similar to the following lines

1. (C) pineapple mango
2. (c) grape
3. (C) mango

The result should return 1 and 3. However my below command seems to work inaccurately. Could you help?

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\PATH" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "(C)*mango" > "SearchMango.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

`Select-String` does a regex match by default, and brackets are used in regexes for grouping characters. You can't use the `-SimpleMatch` parameter, because you're looking for a wildcard in there.

So you need to escape your brackets with the `\` (backslash) character. Also, you need a `.` in front of your `*` for the "any" character in regex.

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\PATH" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "\(C\).*mango" > "SearchMango.txt"
```

or, if you're only matching letter characters or spaces between your (C) and "mango"

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\PATH" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "\(C\)[\w\s]*mango" > "SearchMango.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-5.1

Also, Regexr (https://regexr.com/) is a good site to test your regexes. Try the second one on your sample list - just remember to set the "case insensitive" flag.